# How to count the number of function calls required to find $\binom{n}{r}$ using divide and conquer?

Tags: combinatorics

This function calculates $\binom{n}{r}$ using divide and conquer and I know that the number of function calls required for calculating any $\binom{n}{r}$ is given by $2\binom{n}{r}-1$. I am looking for an explanation for this formula. How to derive this result using simple combinatorics techniques.

```
int binomialCoeff(int n, int k)
{
  // Base Cases
  if (k==0 || k==n)
    return 1;

  // Recurse
  return  binomialCoeff(n-1, k-1) + binomialCoeff(n-1, k);
}
```

Comment: I don't follow your claim to :"know that the number" is $2\binom{n}{r}-1$.  Is this perhaps a typo?  Hint:  try some smallish cases.

Comment: Trace a few call trees through Pascal’s triangle to see what’s going on.

Comment: @hardmath I have written a C++ program which calculates $\binom{n}{r}$ and also calculates the number of times the function is called. Please check it here: http://ideone.com/jXXfnN It does satisfy the formula in my original post.

Comment: Pick an example where $2^n$ is much larger than  $2\binom{n}{r}$.

Comment: @hardmath I tried $n = 20$, $r = 1$, so function calls = $2\binom{20}{1}-1$ = 39 and $2^{20} = 1048576$. It does work according to me. Do you have some case where its not working.

Comment: Try $n=20$ (this is actually excessive) and $r=19$.  Same value of $\binom{n}{r}$, but very different count of function calls.

Comment: @hardmath Why will they have different number of function calls? Check this program here http://ideone.com/ckC5ZG It takes 39 function calls. Note that for some $n$ and $r$ the function can be called multiple times and each time will be counted as a different occurrence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since ultimately you are computing $1+1+\cdots +1$ for $\binom{n}{r}$ values of $1$, you have $\binom{n}{r}$ times where you are returning $1$, and $\binom{n}{r}-1$ times you are doing addition, so you are calling this function $2\binom{n}{r}-1$ times.

You aren't adding them sequentially in order, but you are just bracketing them. For instance, computing $\binom{4}{2}$ as:

$$((1+1)+1)+(1+(1+1))$$

So you are still doing $\binom{n}{r}-1$ additions.

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this is by induction.

The base cases will be both $r=0$ and $r=n$.  Now $\binom{n}{r} = 1$ in both of these cases, and there are no subfunction calls (only the top level call).  Thus the combined number of function calls is $2\binom{n}{r} - 1 = 1$.

In all other cases the function will call itself recursively twice, so in those "induction" cases $0 \lt r \lt n$ we have, besides the top level call, the calls to $n-1$ choose (resp.) $r-1$ and $r$.  Thus the number of function calls to compute $\binom{n}{r}$ in these intermediate (induction) cases is (by appealing to the induction hypothesis):

$$ 1 + (2\binom{n-1}{r-1} - 1) + (2\binom{n-1}{r} - 1)$$

A little simplification and Pascal's triangle rule gives us $2\binom{n}{r} - 1$.

To be more formal we would treat this as an induction on $n$, where the base cases $n= 0,1$ are as trivial as what I called the base case above.  In one point of view my base cases are the bordering ones of Pascal's triangle, and the counting of function calls mirrors, as Thomas Andrew's Answer outlines, the computation of entries in that triangle.